# Returning exception is not complete when using Owin TestServer

Tags: c#, asp.net-web-api, asp.net-web-api2, owin

I have a web api and I want to test it. When I call it using browser, it returns a json like:

```
{
    message: "An error has occurred.",
    exceptionMessage: "Self referencing loop detected with type ......",
    exceptionType: "Newtonsoft.Json.JsonSerializationException",
    stackTrace: " at Newtonsoft.Json.Serialization.JsonSerializerInternalWriter.CheckForCircularReference(JsonWriter writer, Object value, JsonProperty property, JsonContract contract, JsonContainerContract containerContract, JsonProperty containerProperty) 
                    at Newtonsoft.Json.Serialization.JsonSerializerInternalWriter.SerializeList(JsonWriter writer, IEnumerable values, JsonArrayContract contract, JsonProperty member, JsonContainerContract collectionContract, JsonProperty containerProperty) 
                    at Newtonsoft.Json.Serialization.JsonSerializerInternalWriter.SerializeValue(JsonWriter writer, Object value, JsonContract valueContract, JsonProperty member, JsonContainerContract containerContract, JsonProperty containerProperty) 
                    "
}
```

but when I'm calling it using Owin `TestServer` in my unit tests it just returns a simple json not having all details:

```
{
    message: "An error has occurred."
}
```

Inside my unit test, I'm calling api like this:

```
var response = OwinServer.HttpClient.GetAsync("api/Products/GetAll").Result;
if (response.StatusCode != HttpStatusCode.OK)
{
    var errorStr = response.Content.ReadAsStringAsync().Result;
    Assert.Fail(errorStr)   // this errorStr is not complete enough!
}
```

What can I do have a complete error, specially the **stackTrace**?